# `build-dep` download location?

Tags: nautilus, compiling

I downloaded build dependency of nautilus with

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nautilus
```

now; where can I find its .h and .cpp files?

Comment: Build-dep automatically downloads and installs the necessary dependencies, I don't think you'll find any C files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the right command, `build-dep` donwloads the build dependency required to compile the Nautilus source code but they are NOT Nautilus sources.

To get them type:

```
sudo apt-get source nautilus
```

It will download and extract nautilus in the same folder where you launched `apt-get source`.

On a 13.10 system I now have a `nautilus-3.8.2` with a `src` subfolder.

Alternatively, you can get Nautilus source from the Ubuntu package [page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/saucy/nautilus).

Comment: Is nautilus-3.8.2 in home folder?

Comment: if you ran `apt-get source` from your home directory you should get nautilus-3.8.2 in the same place